Module federation: Unsatisfied version 18.3.1 from `REMOTE-REPO-C` of shared singleton module react (required ^17.0.1)
I am using module federation for micro-frontends, where the host is react:^17 and some of the remote repos also have react:^17.
I want to upgrade all the repos to ^18 in a step by step manner with one repo at a time.
But I am getting an error "Unsatisfied version 18.3.1 from REMOTE-REPO-C of shared singleton module react (required ^17.0.1)'"
Below are the webpack configs:
Host: => Lets call it A
            react: {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: '^17.0.1',
            },
            'react-dom': {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: '^17.0.1',
            },
            'react-router-dom': {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: '^5.2.0',
            },
            swr: {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
            },

Remotes with react/react-dom version 17 => Lets call it B
            react: {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: '^17.0.1',
            },
            'react-dom': {
              eager: true,
              singleton: true,
              requiredVersion: '^17.0.1',
            },

Remote with react/react-dom version 18 => Lets call it C
        react: {
            eager: true,
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: '^18.3.1' 
        },
        'react-dom': {
            eager: true,
            singleton: true,
            requiredVersion: '^18.3.1'
        },

I am able to see the components from the C, but the data which is being fetched in C is not getting updated in A.
I have checked other answers related to this (Webpack Module Federation Unsatisfied version 11.x.x of shared singleton module @angular/common (required ^7.2.0) , Module Federation, React, and Apollo 3 warnings),
mostly suggested to change to required version but it didn't help me.
How can I make it work?
